# Why reduce() skip square brackets?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, brackets

I have this code:

```js
var isValid = function(s) {
    let arr = [...s];

    arr.reduce((acc, cur) => {
        console.log(`arr in reduce: ${arr}`);
        console.log(`acc: ${acc}`);
        console.log(`cur: ${cur}`);
        if ((acc && cur)
        && (
            (acc === '(' && cur === ')')
            || (acc === '{' && cur === '}')
            || (acc === '[' && cur === ']')
        )) {
            arr.splice(arr.indexOf(acc), 2);
            console.log(`arr after splice: ${arr}`);
            return arr;
        }
        else {
            console.log(`else statement: ${cur}`);
            return cur;
        }
    });

    return arr.length === 0 ? true : false;
};

console.log(isValid("()[]{}"));
```

It needs to return true if:

- Open brackets must be closed by the same type of brackets.
- Open brackets must be closed in the correct order.

My code doesn't pass this test `"()[]{}"`: it always returns `[,]` and I don't understand why. I've tried using regex, anscii for the square brackets but it doesn't work.

Comment: Unrelated, but you seem to be mapping an array to itself at the top.

Comment: Because the parameter `s` is a string.

Comment: but `let arr = [...s];` is sufficient to make it an array, the `map` is useless

Comment: use `split`, like `s.split('')`, then you'll get an array of `chars`

Comment: @Viet but `[...s]` already makes an array out of each character the `.map(x => x)` (simplified) makes another array out of that array identical to the first one

Comment: `.reduce()` seems like a really awkward way of doing this.

Comment: `return arr;` - so next time `acc` is the entire array.

Comment: You guys are correct. `[...s]` does spread the string and make an array from it, but I wanted to call the new array inside the `reduce()`. I don't want to call [...s] again every time I use `s` as an array but it's the wrong way to do it. I'll edit it. Thank you.

Comment: @Viet it's because `splice` changes the length, you'll notice by looking at the logs that `[,]` is skipped in the tests because of that. You should probably use a copy instead of the the original array when you splice

Comment: `return arr;` doesn't solve the issue. use a copy of a spliced array also doesn't work.

Comment: `return arr;` is one of the problem. An other one is that you are modifying an Array over which you are looping (just try  `arr.reduce((a,b)=>{console.log(b); arr.length=0},0)`. But using `reduce` is the major one, when all you need is a for loop with a backreference lookup.

Comment: @Viet `return arr` *is* an issue. Just not the only one.

Comment: @Viet I didn't mean use a copy of the sliced array, I meant slice a copy of the array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take an object for the expected closing characters and if an open character is found push the expected closing character to a stack.

Otherwise check the popped value against the character.

```js
var isValid = function([...array]) {
        var stack = [],
            open =  { '(': ')', '[': ']', '{': '}' };
        return array.every(c => c in open ? stack.push(open[c]) : c === stack.pop())
            && !stack.length;
    };

console.log(isValid("()[]{}"));
console.log(isValid("(({}[()]))[]{}"));
console.log(isValid("()[]{}}"));
console.log(isValid("["));
```

Comment: This doesn't pass this test: `s = '['`.

Comment: Thank you @NinaScholz. FYI: Runtime: 60 ms, faster than 75.19% of JavaScript online submissions for Valid Parentheses.
Memory Usage: 34.8 MB, less than 28.38% of JavaScript online submissions for Valid Parentheses.

Comment: do i get a badge?

Comment: How do you get one or how can I give you one?

Comment: Slightly modified version which ignores non brackets and errs on single open ones: https://jsfiddle.net/u1tnh7sa/

Answer (score 3):

Because splice changes the length, you'll notice by looking at your logs that [,] is skipped in the tests because of that (the current index in the `reduce` steps don't correpond to the array any more). You should probably use a copy instead of the the original array when you splice, and test this array instead:

Note that the way your code is made, it won't work with nested parenthesis/brackets. You should also be careful about the use of `indexOf` to find the `cur`, because it will return the first found, which if you change your code, might not correspond to your real `cur`.

```js
var isValid = function(s) {
    let arr = [...s], copy = [...s];

    arr.reduce((acc, cur) => {
        console.log(`arr in reduce: ${arr}`);
        console.log(`copy in reduce: ${copy}`);
        console.log(`acc: ${acc}`);
        console.log(`cur: ${cur}`);
        if ((acc && cur)
        && (
            (acc === '(' && cur === ')')
            || (acc === '{' && cur === '}')
            || (acc === '[' && cur === ']')
        )) {
            copy.splice(copy.indexOf(acc), 2);
            console.log(`copy after splice: ${copy}`);
            return arr;
        }
        else {
            console.log(`else statement: ${cur}`);
            return cur;
        }
    });

    return copy.length === 0 ? true : false;
};

console.log(isValid("()[]{}"));
```

Comment: Your solution is correct, I think, but I run into this error:

```
TypeError: Reduce of empty array with no initial value.
```

Comment: for which test case you have this error? it works in the snippet

Comment: It does work in the snippet. Honestly I don't know which test case. I only know your code passes 4/76 tests. You can try it here: https://leetcode.com/problems/valid-parentheses/

Comment: As I said in the answer, this code won't work with nested parenthesis. This answer answers only your question ("Why reduce() skip square brackets?"), I didn't rewrite your code to a fully working one that does what you expect. With a bit of humour, i'd say Nina gave you a fish, and I tried to teach you how to fish ;)